# Installing quelpa-use-package from use-package

Tags: init-file, package, use-package

Currently I have the following init file to install and use `use-package`:

```
;; Package.el
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil) 
(add-to-list 'package-archives  '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

;; use-package
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))


;; use use-package
;; (use-package some-pack :ensure another-pack)
```

Not all packages work with `use-package`, so I am extending it with `quelpa`. I need to install both the extension and `quelpa` itself. It seeems it could work like this:

```
(use-package quelpa-use-package
  :ensure t
  :init
  (setq quelpa-update-melpa-p nil)
  (setq quelpa-self-upgrade-p nil))
```

If I start my init file in this way, I do not get any error. However, when I try to add a git package, such as
[matrix-client](https://github.com/alphapapa/matrix-client.el):

```
(use-package matrix-client
  :quelpa (matrix-client :fetcher github :repo "alphapapa/matrix-client.el"
                         :files (:defaults "logo.png" "matrix-client-standalone.el.sh")))
```

I get at startup:

```
Error (use-package): Failed to parse package matrix-client: use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :quelpa
```

How can I install `quelpa-use-package` from `use-package`? (If I can)

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error: "use-package: Unrecognized keyword: :quelpa" with emacs 26.3.
And after I:

- Verified packages installed: use-package, quelpa, quelpa-use-package ( I installed them all by M-X package-install)
- Add below to my .emacs file

```
(require 'use-package)
(require 'quelpa-use-package)
```

The command (which was similar to your command) worked correctly:

```
(use-package gdb-mi :quelpa (gdb-mi :fetcher git
  :url "https://github.com/weirdNox/emacs-gdb.git"
  :files ("*.el" "*.c" "*.h" "Makefile"))
  :init
  (fmakunbound 'gdb)
  (fmakunbound 'gdb-enable-debug))
```

May this help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Emacs 29 and this is how I bootstrap `quelpa` and `quelpa-use-package` using `use-package`.

```
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives
      '(("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
      use-package-always-ensure t)

(package-initialize)

(require 'use-package-ensure)

(use-package quelpa
  :ensure)

(use-package quelpa-use-package
  :demand
  :config
  (quelpa-use-package-activate-advice))
```